# How would i access the mySql database in lucee Docker Container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my lucee project running in one docker container. I can't access the lucee admin for that port no. How could I set the data source in that port and how to connect mysql database?

*Please help me to connect mysql in docker ?*

Comment: how U start container ?

Comment: start container by using that command "docker run -p 8888:8888 myluceeapp "

Comment: Did you build the luncene container or you used some official image? Does it run mysql inside the image or you need to provide it a mysql ?